# Append String to Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, append

I want to append text to label on `CheckChanged` Event, I Have tried the following code but it does not seem to work. Could you suggest me what to change?
here is my code

```
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox2.Visible = false;
    DropDownList2.Visible = true;
    CheckBox3.Visible = true;
    Label2.Text += "-" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
}

protected void CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox3.Visible = false;
    DropDownList3.Visible = true;
    CheckBox4.Visible = true;
    Label2.Text += "-" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: How is your Dropdown are populate? try `DropDownList3.SelectedValue.ToString()` or `DropDownList3.Text`

Comment: Have you had any luck fixing this?

Comment: not yet still stuck :/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `selectedvalue` try for `Text` property.

```
 Label2.Text += "-" + DropDownList2.Text;
```

It will be as follows:

```
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox2.Visible = false;
    DropDownList2.Visible = true;
    CheckBox3.Visible = true;
    Label2.Text += "-" + DropDownList2.Text;
}

protected void CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox3.Visible = false;
    DropDownList3.Visible = true;
    CheckBox4.Visible = true;
    Label2.Text += "-" + DropDownList3.Text;
}
```

Comment: have u debugged the code???...do  DropDownList3.SelectedValue gives you proper values?

Comment: i think this code is not perfect bu .value you will also get value and its consider as a string.so no need to do with dropdownlist.text

Comment: Yeah, but since it was not working with selected value i suggested text property

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString()`.

Or you could `cast` the `SelectedItem` to append a specific property.

Answer (score 0):

use `SelectedItem.Text`

```
Label2.Text += "-" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: When I Do that It Shows me the following error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: When you are coming to this line is any item selected at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You better use single `StringBuilder` for that purposes: operate string data with it and assign its current buffer to Labels's `Text` property

Comment: Although it hasn't been explicitly stated, the problem seems to be the value that `SelectedValue` is returning. So how the string is being appended and assigned to isn't the problem. At least not yet until the first problem is resolved. A `StringBuilder` however is a good idea and using its `Append` method is more efficient than `+=`

Answer (score 0):

I think you use:

```
Label2.Text =Labe2.Text + "-" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
```